# Why does Mercurial think my source files are binary?

Tags: windows, mercurial, binary-files

I've been working on a programming project in Notepad, so far. Today, I opened my source files in an IDE to debug one thing, and the IDE converted saved my files as binary (or so Mercurial reports, even though I can open and edit them without any problems in Notepad).

How do I convert these binary files back to ASCII, so that I can track my changes in Mercurial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UTF-16 files are considered by Mercurial to be "not text". Change your IDE to save the files as UTF-8 or ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

Quickest way I can think of is to open the file up in Notepad, click `File` > `Save As`, and change the Encoding setting.

[image]